# Binding jquery to an updated element via Ajax

Tags: jquery

This question has been asked but this one is a little more specific, the others didn't give me an answer, thou they helped.

I have some html code like so, it's this way AFTER the j query executes:

```
<td><div class="switch has-switch"><div class="switch-animate switch-off"><input type="checkbox" data-toggle="switch" data-shopify="10700" data-order="90312" class="ct-primary printing" value="0"><span class="switch-left">DONE</span><label>&nbsp;</label><span class="switch-right">NOT</span></div></div></td>
```

The above html is just a check box that I can check or uncheck.
Using the following Jquery code the above gets the div added to it:

```
  $(function () {
    $('.switch').each(function () {
      $(this).bootstrapSwitch();
    });

    $('[data-toggle="switch"]').each(function () {
      $(this).wrap('<div class="switch" />').parent().bootstrapSwitch();
    });
  });
}(jQuery);
```

My challenge is when I pull data from Ajax it no longer works since the J query has already loaded.  I've read to use "on" but I'm not sure where I would add that into this current J query code.  How can I change this code to work on new elements provided by an Ajax call?

Comment: Will need to initialize plugin on new html after you load it with ajax. Show us how you are loading it

Comment: Challenge is I am placing Ajax on an html page that already displays data.  I'm trying to avoid refresh of whole page.  Should I refresh the script when I do Ajax?  @charlietfl

Comment: Basically yes... But you don't want to double wrap so should only target what is added

Comment: Ok got it, thank you! @charlietfl

Comment: Read this: Understanding Event Delegation https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)